# Re-routing packets due to packet loss from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, dns, routes

I'm getting significant packet loss out of an EC2 instance talking to a particular server.

```
mtr <site domain>
```

returns the following:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the route going through this particular server in Tokyo.   A fresh EC2 instance in the same region/AZ doesn't seem to go through this route.

I have cleared route cache (didn't help).

This seems to only happen on a couple of older EC2 instances.  A new instance with the EBS attached from the older box the same issue occurs.

What can I do to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to be an AWS global infrastructure issue, and not something the customer can control at the instance or even VPC level. Under the [AWS  shared responsibility model](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/), global infrastructure is 100% AWS responsibility. The customer cannot change any configuration at that level.

Comment: I'm not sure the responsibility model for each point along the route is AWS' responsibility.   They don't own all of them :)

Comment: No of course. But AWS is 100% responsible for **its** own global infrastructure, and not the customer. So you cannot change any routing once the packet leaves the VPC.